# Google PHP BigQueryClient returning Numeric Object instead of just the value for Numeric fields

Tags: php, google-bigquery

When I run a bigquery select using PHP BiqQueryClient, the data returned for 'Numeric' fields is an object. The strings and integer fields are returned as values.

```
<?php 
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$query = "SELECT customer_name, customer_number FROM mytable;";
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(['projectId' => $projectId]); 
$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($queryJobConfig);
if($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
       print_r($row);
    }
}
?>
```

Prints something like:

```
Array
([customer_number] => Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Numeric Object(
 [value:Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Numeric:private] => 18302117
))
```

How can I simply get an numeric value returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at class implementation here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery/blob/master/src/Numeric.php it has a method `get()` that returns the value:

```
$customerNumber = $row['customer_number'];
print_r($customerNumber->get());
```

Comment: get() is a suitable solution. Thank you.

Comment: Perfectoo answer. Thanks!